# regionprop on x y corrdinates object - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a txt file containing coordinates (x y in multiply rows). As I use `readtable` I get it as 2 column table. How can convert it to logical so I use on it `regionprop`?

Comment: Depending upon which properties you need, it might be easier to just compute the image moments yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily using the [`sparse`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) function:

```
t = table([5; 2; 3; 4], [2; 3; 3; 1]); % example table with two columns
y = full(sparse(t{:,1}, t{:,2}, true)); % or full(sparse(t{:,2}, t{:,1}, true));
```

This gives

```
y =
  5×3 logical array
   0   0   0
   0   0   1
   0   0   1
   1   0   0
   0   1   0
```

If the table can have repeated entries, use

```
y = full(sparse(t{:,1}, t{:,2}, 1)); % or full(sparse(t{:,2}, t{:,1}, 1));
```

to get a count of the number of times each coordinate pair appears in the table; and then maybe convert to `logical`. This can also be done with [`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
y = accumarray([t{:,1} t{:,2}], 1); % or accumarray([t{:,2} t{:,1}], 1)
```